# Crop large images, but pad small ones

Tags: crop, imageresizer, pad

I want to display a 1920px by 335px version of user provided images on a web site, using [ImageResizer v4](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/reference).

I would like to use **cropping** in case the image is larger than the given dimensions, but **padding** if it is smaller, and in between I would like to shrink the image and add padding to achieve the target dimensions.

I know I can do cropping using `?w=1920&h=335&mode=crop` but it won't reach the target dimensions if it is too small. Adding `&scale=up` will not look good on small images because the image is then first scaled up and then cropped.

On the other hand, using padding I would give away a lot of image pixels in case of large source images, when I could really crop them (down) to the target size.

Can anybody advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `&mode=crop` with `&scale=canvas` to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan, I couldn't find this option in the (official?) docs: http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/reference - am I missing something? Do you have that option documented somewhere?

Comment: &scale=upscalecanvas is documented, but &scale=canvas is also supported.

Comment: It's never too late ;-)